# Change server date using PHP

Tags: php, linux

Is this possible to change linux server date using php code.Is there any way to give necessary permissions to apache to do this ?

Comment: it is possible to flush away everything from linux, until the administrator is intelligent enough !!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can make a server present dates/times which correspond to a timezone other than it's default.

### PHP `ini_set()`

In a php file which is included in every page which deals with date and time, include something like

```
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Los_Angeles');
```

Which will result in any dates/times being handled as though they are local times for Los Angeles, America.

See: ["Changing the timezone with PHP"](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-change-timezone/)

### .htaccess

If you have sufficient privileges, and the server configuration allows it, rather than having to include the above in any php file which deals with dates and times, you could put in a .htaccess file

```
SetEnv TZ "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Which will have the same effect.

See: ["Change timezone with htaccess"](http://www.webmastersucks.com/change-time-zone-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Read about so called setuid bit, but use it very carefully.